# Grey artifacts in glass bottle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass, artifacts

I am using Cycles render engine. The glass material has a color of full white, roughness of 0 and an ior of 1.5. I was on a different forum given the suggestion to increase max bounces of the scene, currently i have 20 total, 4 diffuse, 20 glossy, 8 transmission, 0 volume and 8 transparent.
[image: glass artifacts]

Here is how my bottle looked when modelling it in maya.

[image: picture of bottle in maya]

Edit1: added blender file link
[image]

Comment: to me it looks like the reflection of the grey backround, no?

Comment: @moonboots if i remove the background theyre still there https://gyazo.com/27308cd11661ba68c385549b58c48a4a

Comment: That's how it should look isn't it? You're looking through the thickness of the bottle glass in that area and that's what I'd expect ot see. Try it with a real glass bottle and compare the two.

Comment: I notice the screenshot I added to the post doesn't make it look as bad as other angles do. I don't think it's supposed to be this "spotty" and uneven. https://gyazo.com/7638ca7c0172e66f92a4d85e7d9d3185

Comment: maybe give a Subdivision Surface modifier to your bottle? (with a Subdivision level of 2)

Comment: @moonboots here is a screenshot using sub lvl 4 https://gyazo.com/eaa8180e242ccb4ee54ee3d4d85e0c4f certainly looks a lot better. What I'm concerned about is this part.. https://gyazo.com/8c0ebc703fdd748dd9c8d426c8b30ee6

Comment: Before working on the glass refractions... let's clean up the model a bit: your fluid domain is in the shape of the bottle - that's creating a lot of wasted geometry. The fluid domain will always be calculated in a cuboid form and doesn't take other shapes into account. Then you subtracted a mesh called "boolean" from it with the _Boolean_ modifier, which is unnecessary as well. The "boolean" also has an unused _Boolean_ modifier on it which can be deleted. And for the refractions, the _Transparent_ bounces under _Light Paths_ are set to 8. I would set them to at least 32, better 64.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks! I must've accidentally added a boolean to the domain, it was a square before, like it should be. Increasing the transparent bounces to 64 still has the spotty artifacts. It seems that the spotty streaks appear along the edges when in edit mode for the bottle.. I tried to edit an image to explain what I mean https://gyazo.com/e2da233af4e0cc6d850f85892d902a98

Comment: The other thing is, you have the objects "glassbottle" and "glassbottle_test.001" both visible in render, this surely will make problems, too.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann alright, I have cleaned up my scene a lot now. I removed all the stuff that won't be necessary for now. All the liquid sims are gone since I left them halfway done and I think I'm going to add liquid in some other way anyway. I'm sort of new to using blender to render and simulate stuff so I mess up these kinds of things hehe. I think the bottle looks pretty good now, and when I added an hdri it looks even better now that the reflected parts aren't just an ugly gray color. Edit adding screenshot: https://gyazo.com/d5872d46e435fb279890febcb50b208d

Comment: like Gordon says, you have glassbottle_test.001 overlapping, disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my comments I mentioned the *Transparent* bounces, but they are more important for *Fluid* simulations with liquids or smoke. For glass-like materials there is something much more important, the *Glossy* bounuces. Of course always depending on the geometry, there can be many reflection bounces inside glass objects so that the default *Glossy* bounces value of 2 is almost always too low.

As said before, depending on the geometry you can get quite different results and sometimes a value of 8 is sufficient, whereas other times even with 64 you can still see changes.

I would always suggest at least 16, better are 32. If you don't have a scene filled with hundreds of glass objects even the influence on the render times isn't too strong. Just note that other than the independent *Transparent* bounces, the *Glossy* bounces are limited by the *Total* amount of bounces. Setting them high doesn't matter much if the total bounces are lower.

Here are comparison images with your bottle, you can see there the changes are very subtle and 8 bounces seem to be enough to make it look good:

[image: bottle]

Whereas in the images below, the slightly more complex geometry of the wine glass leads to more internal reflections on glossy surfaces and so there is still a very noticeable change between 16 and 32 bounces.

[image: wine glass]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out what I thought were artifacts are actually how a bottle would look like under similar lighting, it's just that the bottle wasnt subdivided enough. Subdividing made the "artifacts" look less spotty and made it look good. Adding an HDRI also made the reflections look a lot better.

Comment: Sorry when I talked about the _Transparent_ bounces earlier, what I actually meant was the _Glossy_ bounces. I've prepared an answer just as comparison on how they affect the appearance of dark areas in glass.